# Python Import From Path

Tags: python, import, path

I'm using portable-python and haven't been able to find a way of linking .py files to the portable-python interpreter (meaning I can't just double click my scripts to run them). I've been getting around this by dragging scripts into the path portable-python checks and then importing them.

ex:

```
import random_py_file
```

but is there a way to substitute the name of the file with its absolute/relative path?

ex:

```
import C:\file\script.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on linux; however, I am not sure about windows. Essentially what you are doing is adding a path where python will look to find your script.

```
sys.path.append('C:\file')
import script
```

Look [here](http://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables) to find how to make this permanent.

Comment: Does this fully answer your question?

Comment: Would be good to have a way to make the path permanent, but as I worded my question this is a good answer.

Comment: Updated the answer to include this.